# Firefox Addon Status Bar to Addon Bar

Tags: firefox-addon, browser-addons

I have two addons with a decent number of downloads. Both addons are on Status Bar. Now I get a lot of emails that say that status bar is gone, and I need to use addon bar. Doesn't addon bar come automatically if you have addons on status bar?

As a developer, what should I fix?

Comment: You should move to using CustomizableUI.jsm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm - let me know if you need help. With this method, your users also have the option to download an add-on which restores addonbar/statusbar and they can drag it anywhere. But even if users dont, they can drag your tools anywhere in the new ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status bar is gone since quite some time (Firefox 4, really), but there was a compatibility layer that automatically put status bar items from add-ons into the then new add-on bar and automatically toggled the visibility of the add-on bar when this happened.

The Firefox Australis theme, which shipped with Firefox 29, also removed the add-on bar. Again there is a compatibility layer that would place items from the add-on bar into the default toolbar area, but as compatibility layers go, this cannot work with everything, and really only works with standard toolbar buttons added the standard overlay way.

You'll need to convert your statusbar-based stuff to [either toolbar buttons overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Adding_Toolbars_and_Toolbar_Buttons) ([additional remarks for Australis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Australis_add-on_compat)), use the new [`CustomizableUI` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm) or convert your add-on into an SDK add-on and use SDK [`ActionButton` APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action).